# Formula for calculating the deviance of a two level logit random intercepts model?

Tags: logistic, multilevel-analysis, deviance

I am looking for the formula to calculate the deviance of a multilevel logit model. I would like this for both the random intercepts case and the random intercepts and slopes model when there are two levels.